How to define a function for Schmitt trigger?
Schmitt trigger is very popular in analog circuits. The output retains its value until the input changes sufficiently. It can be mathematically described as below:
$$x\geq0.5, y(x)=1$$
$$-0.5<x<0.5,y(x)=1\text{ or } -1$$
$$x\leq-0.5, y(x)=-1$$

Is it possible to define y(x) or y(x(t),t) in someway such that we can plot it directly when x(t) and the initial value of y are given?
I can only plot it by using NDSolve.
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t], WhenEvent[x[t] - 0.5 > 0, y[t] -> 1], WhenEvent[x[t] + 0.5 < 0, y[t] -> -1], x[0] == -1, y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}, DiscreteVariables -> {y}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, PlotLabels -> {"y(x)"}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]



Thiis expression $-0.5<x<5,y(x)=1\text{ or } -1$ is not any math function (see Function, especially "assigns to each element of $X$ exactly one element of $Y$").

OP, your proposed solution seems valid, no? NDSolve should give you an interpolated function you can use to plot the curve.

Obviously, we need a function with memory. For this we may use a module with a localized variable:
strig[x_] = Module[{mem = False},
  Which[
   x >= 0.5, mem = True; 1,
   x <= -0.5, mem = False; -1,
   -0.5 < x < 0.5, If[mem, 1, -1]
   ]
  ]

If we plot this from -1 to 1 and back:
ListLinePlot[{Table[{x, st[x]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, st[x]}, {x, 1, -1, -0.1}]}]



The Schmitt trigger is not a function because it has memory,
but it is a respectable object in the sense of Object Oriented Programming.
Of course, in this new context some difficulties appear :

When are two objects the "same object" ?
what is the initial state of the object at first use ?
What do we call "the first use" if the object is used "occasionnaly" in the code.

Here is a solution that takes care of all these problems.

One or several objects (object = schmitt trigger) are created by instanciation.

Objects have a unique name (for example schmidt$5910)

If the input x of a newly created schmitt trigger is in the dead zone, the
trigger begin is life in the state thresthold=+0.5

Objects  keeps their state until they are destroyed. The principe of
mathematica is that objects are destroyed when they are no longer
referencable (a complicated subject, there may be hidden
references).
-x-
 createSchmidt02 := Module[{schmidt}
   , schmidt[x_] := Which[
     x <= -.5, schmidt["threshold"] = .5; -1
     , x >= .5, schmidt["threshold"] = -.5; 1
     , True (* dead zone *), If[
      ! NumericQ[schmidt["threshold"]]
      , schmidt["threshold"] = 0.5; -1 (* 
      if x is in the dead zone at the beginning, 
      initial state is supposed to be "threshold" = +0.5 *)
      , If[schmidt["threshold"] > 0, -1, 1]]
     ]
   ; schmidt
   ]    

 mySchmidt00 = createSchmidt02  


 {ListLinePlot[{#, mySchmidt00[#]} & /@ Range[-1.5, 1.5, .1]]
  , ListLinePlot[{#, mySchmidt00[#]} & /@ Range[1.5, -1.5, -.1]]}




